# Can I dial * or # in android

Tags: java, android

I want to make  android application that has a button to dial *133# programatically. Is it possible or it is restricted. I have tried for iOS but it does not work

Thanks

Comment: It should be possible as there are many apps that provide dialing support with * and #.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but you should and let us know your findings as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can dial anything as long as it is not considered as a system code for the phone. (like a hidden menu)

Comment: I mean in my country when we check balance we should dial *133#, I want to have a button that automatically dial this. Can this be done. Thanks

Comment: This worked for me in my country

Comment: What did you have to dial to check the balance

Comment: #123# but checked for other codes at the time, *133# should work

Comment: Thank you so much appreciate it